# What is MII (Media Independent Interface) and RMII (Reduced Media Independent Interface) in STM32 Boards

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide, stm32h7

I actually wanted to know the major differences between MII and RMII like what is it, why is it used and how is it used in STM32 EVKs

Tried searching on some websites but didn't get a clear idea about MII and RMII and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: It is used mainly to connect Ethernet chips. RMII has less "wires" and requires less pins

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media-independent_interface

Comment: also it depends on the STM32 board whether it can take MII and RMII right